# React Native change color value in color.js config file to change theme?

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, colors, themes, native

I am trying to accomplish the following: user clicks a button that changes the primary color of my application to reflect the color of button, (User clicks blue button, then the theme switches from current color to blue)

Currently I have all of my styles in my colors.js where all of the colors are stored in an object:

```
export default {
  primary: 'red',
  dark: '#212121',
  ...
  ...
  ...
};
```

When I want to use a color from the object, I just import the file into my desired component then to set a color I would do this:

```
container: {
  backgroundColor: colors.primary,
}
```

I would think I should be using state to switch the color then store the value in AsyncStorage, But I am lost to where to set it. Any guidance for a solution would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: got solution for this?

Comment: @ArnoldBrown Redux, it will solve 99% of your problems!

Comment: yes I am using redux. How to replace a primary color in globalColor.js with the color from Api?

Comment: You should have two colors stored in globalColor.js, but have in memory which color is active out of the two. So you will need action to choose between those colors which you will store in a variable somewhere in redux state to then fetch and use in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this colour based on your button click will change the state. So, create one bool variable in state like as follow

```
state = {
    isButtonPress: false
}
```

Now, suppose your button press will call method name as buttonPress, So update value of isButtonPress inside this by calling setState Method:

```
buttonPress = () => {
    this.setState({isButtonPress: !isButtonPress})
}
```

This code will change value of isButtonPress to true and false alternatively when button pressed.

Now in your UI part, just update code as follow for your view

```
<View style={container, {backgroundColor: this.state.isButtonPress ? colors.primary : colours.dark />
```

I hope this will fixed your issues. This code will run every-time when you click on button due to used state variable.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply, the thing is there are going to be more than two colours/themes to choose from.  Also, I don’t think I can play with state because the background needs to be changed on more than one page (every page will have the new primaryColor updated. I should have been more clear, my apologies. The way I’m looking at it is - if I can just change the colour value in colors.js, then that will update the primary color on every page. Thanks again!

Comment: @hugger got solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can and should use states.

Your state can be defined as

```
this.state = {
 colorObjectType: "primary"
}
```

Then on a button click you can define what attribute you want the state to set to, 
`this.setState({colorObjectType: "myProperty"})`.

You can define your style as `<MyComponent style={{backgroundColor: colors[this.state.colorObjectType]}} />`

F.Y.I - A javascript object once declared, can be accessed in two ways

1. this.state.colorObjectType
2. this.state["colorObjectType"]

Comment: I see what you're saying, this is quite clear to me. The only thing I am trying to wrap my head around is which component I need to do this in. I am confused because I have many components who will need the backgroundColor switched from that one state call? Should I be using Redux to do so? Thanks Aseem.

Comment: In my opinion, you should be maintaining a state with all colors mappings for each component. Then probably create a parameterized function which has a component name as an argument and uses the argument to set the style of a specific state. Hope this helps :) @hnicastro

Comment: Hey Aseem. I am now creating my state properly with Redux so I can use the global state in all of my components where this color needs to be applied. I have the color values dispatching properly, but when I add, this.props.theme to my styles object, i get an error saying the value is undefined. I know it is not because when I output the state in a Text tag i get the correct value which is a hex value (which should work in the styles). Would you happen to know why this is an issue? The only thing I can think of would be because the value isnt wrapped in strings. I tried adding .ToString().